# strange behaviour of spark filter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```
A = sc.parallelize(xrange(1, 100))
t = 50
B = A.filter(lambda x: x < t)
print B.collect()
t = 10
C = B.filter(lambda x: x > t)
print C.collect()
```

I want to get all numbers below 50 from A and put them into B, and then get all numbers above 10 from B and put them into C. 
But, the result of `C.collect()` is empty array.

However, if I change

```
m = 10
C = B.filter(lambda x: x > m)
```

It will work fine. 
I can't understand why, on this operation it takes previous `t` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't understand why, on this operation it takes previous t value

Its actually ***not*** referencing to previous t=50 but *is referencing to t=10 itself*

Its more evident if you *write a custom function to print what's happening* as

```
A = sc.parallelize(xrange(1, 100))
t = 50
B = A.filter(lambda x: x < t)
B.collect()
t = 10
def filters(x):
    print x, t
    return x > t
C = B.filter(lambda x: filters(x))
print C.collect()
```

`filters` function will print as following

```
1 10
2 10
3 10
4 10
5 10
6 10
7 10
8 10
9 10
```

It shows that *t is 10* and `B = A.filter(lambda x: x < t)` is being called again with `t=10` **i.e. B now has 1 to 9** and when `.filter(lambda x: x > t)` is called, it returns an *empty list* **as there is no number greater than 10**

As [Spark's official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds) also says

> > By default, each transformed RDD may be recomputed each time you run an action on it. However, you may also persist an RDD in memory using the persist (or cache) method, in which case Spark will keep the elements around on the cluster for much faster access the next time you query it. There is also support for persisting RDDs on disk, or replicated across multiple nodes.